# how do I match a specific number into number set efficiently?

Tags: python

I have a number set which contains 2375013 unique numbers in txt file. The data structure looks like this:

```
11009
900221
2
3
4930568
293
102
```

I want to match a number in a line from another data to the number set for extracting data what I need. So, I coded like this:

```
   6 def get_US_users_IDs(filepath, mode):
   7     IDs = []
   8     with open(filepath, mode) as f:
   9         for line in f:
  10             sp = line.strip()
  11             for id in sp:
  12                 IDs.append(id.lower())
  13         return IDs


  75         IDs = "|".join(get_US_users_IDs('/nas/USAuserlist.txt', 'r'))
  76         matcher = re.compile(IDs)
  77         if matcher.match(user_id):
  78             number_of_US_user += 1
  79             text = tweet.split('\t')[3]
```

But it takes a lot of time for running. Is there any idea to reduce run time?

Comment: Change the way you store the numbers. Put them in a sqlite database and index them. Then use SQL to query.

Comment: Indeed sqlite can be a good solution if your data does not fit in memory. This not the case here (2 millions integer takes less than 20 Mb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood is that you have a huge number of ids in a file and you want to know if a specific user_id is in this file.

You can use a python set.

```
fd = open(filepath, mode);
IDs = set(int(id) for id in fd)
...
if user_id in IDs:
  number_of_US_user += 1
  ...
```

Comment: do I need to use "set" in this case? already the number set has only unique numbers. I just tried your suggestion, but it takes many times also..... . hm..... .

Comment: @MINSUPARK: You should accept this answer by clicking the check mark on the left if ti solved your problem.